# std::ref using with template function and function passing by value

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two functions:

```
void fun(int k) {
    ++k;
}

template<class T> 
void inc(T t) {
    ++t;
}
```

And I call these functions with std::ref:

```
int p = 5;
int o = 5;
fun(std::ref(p));
inc(std::ref(o));
```

After that value of p is 5 and value of o is 6. What is the difference when I call function with std::ref for these functions?

Comment: Is it not obvious?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) returns an [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), which is [*implicitly convertible*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get) to the type it's wrapping.

When calling `fun(std::ref(p))`, you're implicitly converting the newly crated `std::reference_wrapper` to `int`, making a copy.

When calling `inc(std::ref(p))`, you're copying the `std::reference_wrapper` itself, preserving *reference semantics*.

Comment: Better than my answer. Good job.